# editing data with a form

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I am trying to edit data in my database but i cant get it to work.

i have tried breaking the script down to basics and troubleshoot each part.

The delete button works just fine but editting the data doesn't.

Where have i gone wrong?

my structure
database = domains table = domains_info row = domain

```
<?php include("header.php");

//include database connection
include 'db_connect.php';

$action = isset( $_POST['action'] ) ? $_POST['action'] : "";
if($action == "update"){
//write query
$query = "update domains_info 
set
domain = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['domain'])."', 
where id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'";

if( $mysqli->query($query) ) {
    echo "User was updated.";
}else{
    echo "Database Error: Unable to update record.";
}
}
if($action=='delete'){ //if the user clicked ok, run our delete query

$query = "DELETE FROM domains_info WHERE id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."'";
if( $mysqli->query($query) ){
    echo "User was deleted.";
}else{
    echo "Database Error: Unable to delete record.";
}}

$query = "select id, domain
            from domains_info
            where id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'
            limit 0,1";

$result = $mysqli->query( $query );
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$id = $row['id'];
$domain = $row['domain'];?>

<form action='#' method='post' border='0' class="well form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>
    <label class="control-label" for="name">Domain</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo$domain; ?>">
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id ?>' />

    <!-- we will set the action to edit -->
    <input type='hidden' name='action' value='update' />
    <input type='submit' value='Edit' />
  </fieldset>
</form>
<?php echo "<a href='#' onclick='delete_user( {$id} );'>Delete</a>"; ?> 
<script type='text/javascript'>

function delete_user( id ){
//prompt the user
var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete <?php echo$name; ?>?');

if ( answer ){ //if user clicked ok
//redirect to url with action as delete and id of the record to be deleted
window.location = 'deletecontact.php?id=' + id;
} 
}
</script>
```

the error im getting is this

```
Database Error: Unable to update record.
```

Comment: Does it give a MySQL error? Try adding `printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);` below `echo "Database Error: Unable to update record.";`

Comment: There's an extra comma in your UPDATE statement, at the end of the `domain = ` line. If you use `$mysqli->error`, it'll tell you exactly what the issue is.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where id='2'' at line 4

Comment: If you use prepared statements, you don't need to bother with the real_escape_string.

Comment: if i was to add another line to this what would it be ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a extra ',' in your update query

```
 $query = "update domains_info 
 set
 domain = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['domain'])."', 
 where id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'";
```

with

```
 $query = "update domains_info 
 set
 domain = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['domain'])."' 
 where id='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id'])."'";
```

Comment: if i was to add another line to this what would it be ?